# Good way to use react with socket.io

Tags: sockets

I need a hint, I've been using socket-io without react on server side and client side, now that I'm mixing js with it on the client side, I get a little confused. I've seen people declaring it in the componenetDidMount, but I didn't really understood why. I'm looking to here from other users how are you guys using react on with socket on the client side. Any git, explanation or other sources would be great, ty!